# How to read MCP2515 registers from application using sockets?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I have a MCP2515 CAN controller connected to SPI and I am using Sockets to send/receive CAN frame(using sendto/read) in application. How do I read the CANCTRL register of MCP2515 from the application using sockets?

Additional information:- Using Linux and Yocto environment build

Kindly answer at the earliest. Thank you

Comment: Are you going to use it in a non-standard way? Otherwise use CAN socket to communicate with the bus.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways in which this can  be done. The easiest 2 in my opinion are as follows:

1. Using /dev/mem: In linux /dev/mem provides access to system's physical memory. If you know the physical address of CANCTRL register which should be base address of MCP2515 registers + offset of CANCTRL register, you can open /dev/mem and use mmap to map address of CANCTRL register into your applications address space. Then you can access this register using the pointer returned by mmap.
   As an example you can have a look at devmem (A utility to do the same stuff from shell) [source code](https://github.com/brgl/busybox/blob/master/miscutils/devmem.c).

The target address mentioned in above source code should be the physical address of CANCTRL register for your case.

2. If you have access to device driver of MCP2515 CAN controller, you can add a sysfs entry in the driver to export the content of concerned register in a sysfs file. You can see how to use sysfs [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt).

Comment: 1. The way to get into troubles and mess up with the driver.

Comment: It is not possible to use /dev/mem to access the mcp2515 as it is an SPI device and so it is not mapped directly in the SoC memory.

Comment: @AlexandreBelloni thanks for correction. I missed the connected over SPI part, clearly a mistake on my side :)